# Python - Save to PDF screen not displaying in chrome 85.0.4183.102

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

With Reference to the solution from: [Chromedriver Save as PDF method not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55706083/chromedriver-save-as-pdf-method-not-working/63840270#63840270)

Am having issue in displaying Ctrl+P for saving to PDF, the screen appears with all the fields disabled and will closes immediately. Am using the solution provided in the above URL. It used to work perfectly unless i use the below code to disable cookies along with the code you have given.

Am using Chrome driver version: `85.0.4183.102`

Is there any conflict due to this.

```
experimentalFlags = ['same-site-by-default-cookies@2', 'cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure@2']
chromeLocalStatePrefs = {'browser.enabled_labs_experiments': experimentalFlags}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('localState', chromeLocalStatePrefs)
```

Please help me in this regard. Thank you